# Normalise the data in a column between 1-10

Tags: powerbi, dax, normalization

I couldn't publish that question in the Power BI community.

Let me say I have a column illustrated below.

I would like to create a second column and normalize the data in a column between 1-10 in Power BI. How can I do that? Please.

| Data |
| --- |
| 52000 |
| 14000 |
| 2300 |
| 3000 |
| 1300 |
| 170 |
| 75 |
| 15000 |
| 35 |

Comment: Normalize how? Can you specify what you'd like the second column to be?

Comment: Thanks for your ask, Alexis. I don't know what the value of the output will be.
I tried something with this formula:

zi=xi−min(x)max(x)−min(x) `Column = 
VAR Xi = 'my_table'[Column]
VAR MnX = MIN('my_table'[Column])
VAR MxX = MAX('my_table'[Column])
RETURN DIVIDE(Xi-MnX , MxX - MnX)` I would like to put that on a scale of 1 - 10.

Comment: That looks like you are linearly scaling your vector to values in the interval [0,1]. Is that what you're after?  Maybe you can think of a simpler example where you do know the result you want.

Comment: There are millions of ways to normalize or scale your data. You may go for turning you values to percentiles https://www.goodly.co.in/calculate-percentile-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

Your formula scales between 0 to 1. To scale between 1 to 10, you need
[image]

So just multiply the formula by the range, in your case, 10 - 0 = 10 and add the lower end of your scaling interval, i.e, 1